# linq to sql concurrency issue!

Tags: linq-to-sql

i have a windows service which deletes table rows. i dont want it to delete the rows , if the rows are loaded(to do some opertion) by my wcf service . it seems that i should put some locking mechanism , but i cant find on how to do it . any help in this regard ?

thanks
Jamal.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't hold long term database locks. Use some kind of marking technique, such as a table of ids for each loaded row with a foreign key back to the original table. This will prevent deletions until the WCF service deletes the entries in the auxiliary table. It will also enable safe deletion by appending `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM loaded_rows WHERE id = outer.id)` to DELETE statements.

This model even allows multiple "loaders", by adding a "loader_id" column to the auxiliary table.

The main problem with the suggested approach is that the WCF service must delete the rows when it's done with them. If it neglects to this due to a bug or a crash, the rows will be permanently locked (or at least until a DBA wanders by). There are numerous ways to work around this, mostly revolving around some kind of expiry mechanism.